# python - rolling regression + weighted, all without loop?

Tags: python, numpy, regression

is it possible to do the following without loop (so it improves the speed)? i have looked sklearn, sm, and pd, unfortunately don't think they have any direct solution.

i have

```
x = np.array(range(1000))  # ie a standard discrete time series
y = np.append(np.zeros(600),np.random.random(400))  #it has a lot of zeros
y = np.random.permutation(y)  #the number of zeros in b/w the non zero is random
z = np.empty(1000)    # z will contain predicted values from the reg analysis

rolling_window=20
```

i wish to obtain z, where z(i) = a(i)+b(i)x(i) for i within range(1000)
and a(i) and b(i) are obtained by regressing Ys vs Xs for the i b/w (i-rolling_window, i), but only uses Ys that are non zero (hence need to assign weight = 0 for Ys that are zero in the regression. preferably use a weighting method rather than getting rid of the zeros together, because i dont wish to loop)

many thanks in advance